# Accessing Class implementing generic abstract class

Tags: java, generics, abstract

when i try to instantiate an object, from a class that extends a generic abstract class. It won't let me since the generic abstract class does not have a suitable constructor.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass<T> {

    private final Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractClass(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }    
}
```

this is the generic abstract class I am talking about.

```
public class Imp extends AbstractClass {

    public Imp(Class entityClass) {
        super(entityClass);
    }

}
```

If i want to ever access the Imp class, then I would try to instantiate it through a normal constructor. But i get following error when trying:

```
public class Imp extends AbstractClass {

    public Imp(){

    }

    public Imp(Class entityClass) {
        super(entityClass);
    }

}
```

constructor AbstractClass in class AbstractClass cannot be applied to given types required: Class

So if i understand correctly, by extending a generic abstract class you cannot instantiate the class anywhere ever?

If not being able to access the Imp class from other classes, how should I ever use the class?

Comment: Makes sense that you can’t extend AbstractClass without fulfilling it’s constructor requirement.  How can it be expected to fulfill it’s expected purpose if the entityClass is missing.

Comment: You cannot use no argument constructor for Imp either, because its super class has no-arg constructor, unless you call super(your_entity_class) in Imp()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to extend it like that:

```
public class Imp<T> extends AbstractClass<T> {

    public Imp() {
        super(null); // you need to call an existing constructor from superclass (nothing specific about generic classes)
    }

    public Imp(Class<T> entityClass) {
        super(entityClass);
    }
}
```

Never use a generic class without generic parameters.

Just guessing, but maybe you actually want something like this:

```
public class IntegerImpl extends AbstractClass<Integer> {

    public IntegerImpl () {
        super(Integer.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a no-arg constructor to initialize Imp class, then AbstractClass should have this (no-arg) constructor as well, but 'entityClass' property cannot be final anymore in this case.

This could lead to possible null pointer exceptions if you use 'entityClass' without not null checks.